# C# LINQ case when

Tags: c#, linq

I have a short question about making LINQ like this:
I have to find a record 'event' from database based on its field named 'eventname'. That field can be "%abc" or "abc%" or "%abc%" depending on each particular case.

```
int pos; 
//define the position of % in finding string, pos=1: %abc, pos=2: abc%, pos=3: %abc%

var SQLquery =
  (from event evn in database.events
    where (
       case pos=1: evn.CarNumber.EndsWith(string))
       case pos=2: evn.CarNumber.StartsWith(string))
       case pos=3: evn.CarNumber.Contains(string))
    select new DataRecord
       {
       ...
       };
```

Is there any way to handle this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Thank to King King, it works well with

```
var SQLquery =
  (from event evn in database.events
    where (
       (pos==1 && evn.CarNumber.EndsWith(string)) ||
       (pos==2 && evn.CarNumber.StartsWith(string)) ||
       (pos==3 && evn.CarNumber.Contains(string))
    select new DataRecord
       {
       ...
       };
```

Comment: Contains() will work perfectly.

Comment: What kind of LINQ-provider are you using (f.e. Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities)?

Comment: @Amit: Could you explain more about Contains() in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var SQLquery =
       from event evn in database.events
       let carNum = evenloc.CarNumber
       where (pos==1&&carNum.EndsWith(string) ||
              pos==2&&carNum.StartsWith(string) ||
              pos==3&&carNum.Contains(string))
       select new DataRecord
      {
       ...
      };
```

**NOTE**: I think you have some mistake in your query, at this `evenloc`? it looks like some outside-query variable? If so the `condition` may be **always** `true` or `false`, and the `where` clause will become `where true` or `where false` and your query will return all the result or nothing.

Comment: I've not tested this but I'm pretty sure you could use `let carNum = evenLoc.CarNumber` to stop the need to keep looking it up

Comment: @Sayse thanks, I just copied the OP's query and modified the condition, it's worth noticing for the OP.

Comment: sure, [heres the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) (+1ed)

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest using something like this, because its more clear what happens.

```
int pos;
DbContext result = null;

switch(pos)
{
    case 1:
        result = database.events.Where(evenloc => evenloc.CarNumber.EndsWith(string));
        break;

    case 2:
        result = database.events.Where(evenloc => evenloc.CarNumber.StartsWith(string));
        break;

    case 3:
        result = database.events.Where(evenloc => evenloc.CarNumber.Contains(string));
        break;
}
```

Comment: You can't do `var result = null` like that and expect this code to compile. Also: enumerations should never be null, so I would have that default case either throw a `NotImplementedException` or return `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, i post it in a hurry just to show the point of the question

Comment: My original code uses "if pos==0 ..." But I dont like this long way

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
var str = "amitranjan246ranjan007%$%^246";
if(str.Contains("246"))
{
   return true;
}
```

In a layman language, above code will look for the 246 in string str. And it will return true, as it will get that 246 at two positions no matter what other characters are in that string.

King's modified :

```
var SQLquery =
       from event evn in database.events
       let carNum = evenloc.CarNumber
       where (carNum.CarNumber.Contains(string))
       select new DataRecord
      {
       ...
      };
```

Comment: You have "simplified" the problem until it no longer matches the original question. For example: a query on `(pos=2,string="1",car.CarNumber="01")` would return false for the original question and true for yours.